# How to animate shape via state variable in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Trying to animate right side of rectangle in SwiftUI on tap. But it's not working(
It has ratio state var and it's of animatable type (CGFloat). Totally out of ideas why. Please advise.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var animated = false

    var body: some View {
        Bar(ratio: animated ? 0.0 : 1.0).animation(Animation.easeIn(duration: 1))
        .onTapGesture {
            self.animated.toggle()
        }.foregroundColor(.green)
    }
}

struct Bar: Shape {
    @State var ratio: CGFloat

    var animatableData: CGFloat {
        get { return ratio }
        set { ratio = newValue }
    }

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var p = Path()

        p.move(to: CGPoint.zero)

        let width = rect.size.width * ratio
        p.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: 0))

        let height = rect.size.height

        p.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: height))

        p.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: height))

        p.closeSubpath()

        return p
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not needed `@State` for animatable data, so fix is simple

```
struct Bar: Shape {
    var ratio: CGFloat
```

[image]

Tested with this demo view (on Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2)

```
struct TestAnimateBar: View {
    @State private var animated = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Bar(ratio: animated ? 0.0 : 1.0).animation(Animation.easeIn(duration: 1))
                .foregroundColor(.green)
        }
        .background(Color.gray)
        .frame(height: 40)
        .onTapGesture {
            self.animated.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Though I was sure that @State can't spoil anything. Only it's absence can lead to explicit compile time error. Any thoughts why it had such an effect on shape animation?